# Excel Macro - Round Date up to nearest 1st or 15th day of month

Tags: excel, date, vba

**The backstory:**

I'm developing a website for client that is selling subscription products that will only be shipped out in batches on the 1st and 15th of the month.  She will be sending the orders to her fulfillment house and is not too tech savvy, so I need to write a macro for her that will automatically delete any rows from the orders export csv file that do not belong in the current shipment, i.e. remove subscription orders that have expired and old non-subscription orders.  The order export will always include orders from all time.

**Data I have to work with:**

- ORDER CREATION DATE - timestamp of order
- SUBSCRIPTION LENGTH - Subscriptions are available for 3,6,9 or 12 months (She also sells non-subscription items, which will have a length of 0)

**Data I want to create with macro:**

- BATCH DATE(Date of shipment it will go out in)
- LAST SHIPMENT(What's the last shipment batch it will go out in)

**How I think the macro will work:**

1. CREATE BATCH DATE - Populate BATCH DATE column by rounding "Order Creation Date" value up to the next shipment date(1st or 15th of month)
2. CREATE LAST SHIPMENT - Populate LAST SHIPMENT column with the sum of SUBSCRIPTION LENGTH and BATCH DATE
3. DELETE EXPIRED ORDERS - Delete the rows of any orders where LAST SHIPMENT < NOW

This seems logical to me and from poking around on some sites it all seems possible in Excel, I just can't seem to get the first part(rounding up the next 1st or 15th of month) working, which is really the keystone of the whole thing!

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Help yes, create on demand no.  Nudge in the right direction, think of the date as mathematical value and apply logical checks to it with > and <

Comment: see my answer for a function that provides the next shipping date, but it is recommended to always post the code you have tried so far as it helps us understand more precisely the exact areas you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Your question involves several things but you state your main issue is with working out the whole round up date thing, so I do not address matters that are quite simple once you understand the date bit.

The below demonstrates an approach to work out the ship date based on an order or whatever date.

It is a simple list of condition checks adding to day or month or year as necessary. Your treatment if the day is the 1st or 15th already was not perfectly unambigous but the below assumes an order booked on the 1st or the 15th can fulfill on the same day.

You should be able to adapt the approach to handle your other request r.e. final shipping date.

```
Function GetShippingDate(orderDate As Date) As Date

    Dim mYear As Integer, mMonth As Integer, mDay As Integer

    mYear = Year(orderDate)
    mMonth = Month(orderDate)
    mDay = Day(orderDate)

    If mDay > 1 And mDay < 15 Then
        mDay = 15
    ElseIf mDay > 15 Then
        mDay = 1
        mMonth = mMonth + 1
    End If
    If mMonth > 12 Then
        mMonth = mMonth - 12
        mYear = mYear + 1
    End If

    GetShippingDate = DateSerial(mYear, mMonth, mDay)

End Function
```